# How can I flash the tab of a hidden DockableWindow inside Arcmap

Tags: c#, tabs, add-in, esri, arcobjects

I have an ESRI Add-In for ArcGIS for Desktop (10.2.1) written in C# with ArcObjects SDK.

The Add-In includes a DockableWindow.  When this DockableWindow is hidden, I would like to be able to flash the DockableWindow's tab inside of Arcmap.exe (NOT the icon for the whole app on the taskbar).

I have not yet found a solution that works.  Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?  Thanks.

I've already tried flashing via FlashWindowEx, which only succeeds in flashing the icon on the task tray.  Passing in the hwnd for the tab inside of Arcmap does not work to flash the tab.  In fact I tried EVERY child hwnd for the entire app with no success.

If I had the code for the tab, I would just make it change colors myself, but the tab is auto generated by arcmap.exe when my window is set to auto hide.

Comment: Do you mean the location were it would be on activation?

Comment: Esri's ArcGIS for Desktop has dockable windows.  If the dockable window is collapsed, a tab appears in the pane where the dockable window would be if not collapsed.  Clicking on the tab opens (or un-collapses) the dockable window.  I want to be able to cause the tab to flash to alert the user that they should click on it to see what has changed in the dockable window.

Comment: To more specifically answer the question... I only want the tab to flash, not the area where the dockable window would be if un-collapsed/activated.